# Search-and-replace on a list of strings - gsub eapply?

Tags: r, replace, gsub, quantmod, string-substitution

Here is a simplified excerpt of my code for reproduction purposes:

```
library("quantmod")
stockData <- new.env()
stocksLst <- c("AAB.TO", "BBD-B.TO", "BB.TO", "ZZZ.TO")
nrstocks = length(stocksLst)
startDate = as.Date("2016-09-01")

for (i in 1:nrstocks) {
    getSymbols(stocksLst[i], env = stockData, src = "yahoo", from = startDate)
}
```

My data is then stored in this environment stockData which I use to do some analysis.  I'd like to clean up the names of the xts objects, which are currently:

```
ls(stockData)
[1] "AAB.TO"   "BB.TO"    "BBD-B.TO" "ZZZ.TO"
```

I want to remove the - and the .TO from all of the names, and have tried to use gsub and eapply, without any success- can't figure out the appropriate syntax.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: This is simple search-and-replace on a list of strings, you shouldn't put 'quantmod' in the title; also the environment where you are doing this is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `as.list` and `gsub`:

```
library("quantmod")
stockData <- new.env()
stocksLst <- c("AAB.TO", "BBD-B.TO", "BB.TO", "ZZZ.TO")
nrstocks = length(stocksLst)
startDate = as.Date("2016-09-01")

for (i in 1:nrstocks) {
    getSymbols(stocksLst[i], env = stockData, src = "yahoo", from = startDate)
}

ls(stockData)
# [1] "AAB.TO"   "BB.TO"    "BBD-B.TO" "ZZZ.TO"

#convert to list for ease in manipulation
stockData = as.list(stockData)

#find . and replace everything after it with ""

names(stockData)=  gsub("[.].*$","",names(stockData))

#alternately you could match pattern .TO exactly and replace with ""

#names(stockData)=  gsub("[.]TO$","",names(stockData))

ls(stockData)
# [1] "AAB"   "BB"    "BBD-B" "ZZZ"  

#convert back to env 
list2env(stockData)
```

Comment: Thanks - I like this method to solve my problem, works great, and I appreciate the detailed explanation.

Comment: Happy to help, also look at `library(PerformanceAnalytics)` for advanced stats and charting features

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using base R functions like `gsub` with `?regex` while learning R, you may find it much easier to operate on strings with the functions in library `stringr`.  You can use `str_replace`:

```
library(stringr)
e.stocks <- list2env(setNames(lapply(stocksLst, function(x) y <- getSymbols(x, env = NULL)), 
                     str_replace(str_replace(stocksLst, "-", ""), "\\.TO", "")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I've decided to use Osssan's solution as I prefer the multiple steps - easier for me to maintain and comment as I'm still a noob!