# Search-and-replace on a set of columns - getting an error trying to gsub

Tags: r, gsub

this is a follow-up to this question: [Search-and-replace on a list of strings - gsub eapply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40541036/search-and-replace-on-a-list-of-strings-gsub-eapply)

I have the following code:

```
library(quantmod)
library(stringr)
stockData <- new.env()
stocksLst <- c("AAB.TO", "BBD-B.TO", "BB.TO", "ZZZ.TO")
nrstocks = length(stocksLst)
startDate = as.Date("2016-09-01")

for (i in 1:nrstocks) {
    getSymbols(stocksLst[i], env = stockData, src = "yahoo", from = startDate)
}

stockData = as.list(stockData)
names(stockData) = gsub("[.].*$", "", names(stockData))
names(stockData) = gsub("-", "", names(stockData))
symbolsLstCl <- ls(stockData)
```

The last post got me this far and I greatly appreciate the help.  Now, I am trying to do a similar replace for the column names as quantmod includes the symbol name in the columns:

```
colnames(stockData$ZZZ)
# [1] "ZZZ.TO.Open"     "ZZZ.TO.High"     "ZZZ.TO.Low"      "ZZZ.TO.Close"    "ZZZ.TO.Volume"   "ZZZ.TO.Adjusted"
```

I can easily update one of the xts objects using colnames, but I want to include this in a loop so I can do it to all.  This is what I had tried, but it fails:

```
eval(parse(text = paste0("colnames(stockData$", symbolsLstCl[i], ")"))) <- eval(parse(text = (paste0("str_replace(colnames(stockData$", symbolsLstCl[i], "), ", "\".TO\", ", "\"\")"))))
```

Which I find strange, as if I use this (where the left side is hard-coded), it works:

```
colnames(stockData$ZZZ) <- eval(parse(text = (paste0("str_replace(colnames(stockData$", symbolsLstCl[i], "), ", "\".TO\", ", "\"\")"))))
```

I have the sneaking suspicion that there is a much better way to update all of the columns for each element in these lists.. any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks, Adam

Comment: Don't use `eval(parse(...))` unless there's no alternative (and there's almost always an alternative). Also, it will probably be easier to work with a list and `lapply` than separate objects and a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
allnames <- lapply(stockData, 
                   function(x) names(x) = gsub(".TO", "", names(x)))

# replace column names
for (i in 1:length(stockData)) {
          names(stockData[[i]]) <- allnames[[i]]
}

# print all column names
for (i in 1:length(stockData)) {
          print(names(stockData[[i]]))
}

[1] "AAB.Open" "AAB.High" "AAB.Low" "AAB.Close" "AAB.Volume" "AAB.Adjusted"
[1] "BBD-B.Open" "BBD-B.High" "BBD-B.Low" "BBD-B.Close" "BBD-B.Volume" "BBD-B.Adjusted"
[1] "ZZZ.Open" "ZZZ.High" "ZZZ.Low" "ZZZ.Close" "ZZZ.Volume" "ZZZ.Adjusted"
[1] "BB.Open" "BB.High" "BB.Low" "BB.Close" "BB.Volume" "BB.Adjusted"
```

Edited: the output were not correct just now.

I suppose this is what you hope to get.